# Filling a specific region inside a sprite with a color in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I have written a simple game, with AndEngine. In this game I want to fill a specific region inside a sprite with a color ( or another sprite ), to show the progress, as shown below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Would you please help me how I can do it? 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me too had one requirement like yours. Below is what I did.

```
CCSprite backgroundSprite = CCSprite.sprite("background.png");                  
addChild(mShipEnergyMeter, 1);

CCSprite forgroundSprite = CCSprite.sprite("foreground.png");                   
forgroundSprite.setScaleX(1f);
forgroundSprite.setScaleY(1f);
backgroundSprite.addChild(forgroundSprite, 0);
```

based on your requirement, you can set scale of foreground sprite so that it looks like progressing. Hope it helps.

Comment: Dear Braj, I have a question, would you please help me?  I have two sprites, 'panelSprite' and 'characterSprite' and they are attached to scene as follows: Scene.attachChild(panelSprite);    panelSprite.attachChild(characterSprite);  This way, the character should be rendered only inside panel sprite, but when I run the program and set different positions to character, I see that it can be rendered out of panel too. I do not want to andengine  show the character sprite out of panel. What's wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as my knowledge is concerned, child positions are independent of parent here. If u move child, parent will be in same position only but reverse is not going to happen. So, based on child positions u cant control rendering. You have to consider parent also I guess.

Answer (score 1):

just make the area that you want to fill transparent and put the filling img under the filled img.

```
while(loaded()!=100){
    dst.set(x,y,x+w,y+h);
    src.set(0,0,loaded()*w/100,h);
    canvas.drawBitmap(back,src,dst,null);
    src.set(0,0,w),h);
    canvas.drawBitmap(front,src,dst,null);
}
loaded = a func that calculates how much % was loaded
return an integer 0-100
```